# What is the best way to handle cross-thread events in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events, invoke

I'm trying to develop a way to fire events from a thread and handle then on the main UI thread. In the event handlers I will be updating the UI, and I would rather not have to check for InvokeRequired everywhere.

I've seen a lot about this from searching, but I've not seen an example anywhere that will work 100% without the possible problems. I've come up with a solution which appears to work, and to the best of my knowledge, addresses the various problems I have read about. I would be keen to hear peoples opinions on this:

```
public static void SafeInvoke<T>(this EventHandler<T> source, object sender, T args) where T : System.EventArgs
{
    EventHandler<T> handler;

    lock (SyncRoot)
    {
        handler = Volatile.Read(ref source);
    }

    if (handler == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (Delegate d in handler.GetInvocationList())
    {
        ISynchronizeInvoke target = d.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;

        if (target == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (target.InvokeRequired)
        {
            target.BeginInvoke(d, new[] { sender, args });
        }
        else
        {
            handler(sender, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `lock(SyncRoot)` section is not needed. Because `source` is passed as a non-ref parameter, there is no possibility of it being changed unless you explicitly do so.

Comment: Well, one thought about InvokeRequired...  this might seem obvious but I'll mention it anyway. InvokeRequired is a convenience-- not a requirement by any means. You don't ever have to check for InvokeRequired because you should be able to know when your code will be executing in a separate thread and when it won't be. Personally, I never use InvokeRequired. I simply just make sure that I use Invoke when I'm in sections of code that will run in worker threads, and I don't use it when I know the code is running in the GUI thread. I've never had any trouble with this approach. Just a thought.

Comment: You code is broken. You're ignoring the function call when target is not `ISynchronizeInvoke`.

Comment: Since your goal is run the code on the UI thread, you could also choose to use `SynchronizationContext` to run code within the UI thread and then execute all of the event handlers.

Comment: @dizzy.stackoverflow To add to that, `Invoke` works *just fine* if called from a UI thread, so in the (hopefully rare) situations in which you don't know if you're no the UI thread or not, you can just call `Invoke` and know it'll work just fine.

Comment: Making threading opaque is never not a mistake.  The subscriber is defenseless against the inevitable staleness of the event delivery as well as the considerable overhead and the non-zero risk for threading races.  At least make it optional and implement the SychronizingObject pattern as used by the .NET framework classes like Process and FileSystemWatcher.

Answer (score -1):

If you are working in .Net 3.5 or higher, you can use Reactive Extensions.  It is well suited for this kind of thing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx

Comment: How does this even qualify as an answer? It doesn't even come remotely close to answering the question asked. You say Reactive Extensions works well to solve this issue? Ok, show some code or at least a link to some code - not a link to what Reactive Extensions is.